# nginx choosing wrong default site

Tags: nginx

Firstly, I know i can specify `default_server` to force a default site, but I want to understand why nginx isn't simply picking the first defined `server` as [documented](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

At the end of the `http` section in nginx.conf I have

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf is just some default proxy config and ssl config

Sites defined are

000-default
example.com
zombo.com

the default site points to a local directory and index.html, the other two point at proxied servers.

000-default

```
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name  aaa-test;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

  location / {
    root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

example.com

```
server {

    server_name example.com *.example.com ;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://10.245.0.19;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }

}
```

zombo.com

```
server {

    server_name zombo.com *.zombo.com ;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://10.245.0.36;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }

}
```

But if I brows to the nginx servers IP, I get an answer from example.com. I've tried renaming the config files to load them in different orders, and always get example.com as the default. Even if I name its config file `zzz.com`

The docs say traffic with no Host header should go to the first virtual host, but I can't seem to make that happen.

If I remove example.com, then traffic goes to the default host, not zombo.com.

I'm really stumped here ...

**Edit: Info requested by comment**

```
# ls -lU /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Oct  3 00:05 example.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Oct  3 00:05 000-default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Oct  2 22:58 zombo.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/zombo.com
```

Comment: Post the output of `ls -lU /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

Comment: Well that's dumb. So I guess I have to use `default_server` to get around terrible globbing ..

Comment: That's (partly) why it's there.

Comment: Wanna post an answer so I can mark as correct? This also seems to explain my issue http://serverfault.com/a/361163

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nginx *is* looking at the first defined `server`, but it isn't the one you think it is.

If you run `ls -lU /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` you will see the directory listing in the actual order it appears on disk, which is the order in which they will be read. This is quite often not the order you are expecting.

Which, of course, is one reason why you can explicitly define a `default_server`.

Comment: Note: this behaviour was changed in 1.3.10 so that files are now included in sorted order rather than raw directory order. http://serverfault.com/a/361163/140324

Comment: Huh. That looks oddly familiar...