# nginx split large configuration file

Tags: nginx, configuration, files

My nginx default configuration file is becoming huge. I'd like to split it to smaller config files, each including only one, maximum 4 locations to each file, so that I can enable/disable them quickly.

Actual file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/

    location /1 {
        config info...;
    }

    location /2 {
        config info....;
    }        
    location /abc {
        proxy_pass...;
    }

    location /xyz {
        fastcgi_pass....;
    }
    location /5678ab {
        config info...;
    }

    location /admin {
        config info....;
    }
```

now, if I want to split that up to have only a few locations in each file (locations belonging together), what would be a proper way to do it without causing chaos (like declaring root in each file, hence having weird path's that nginx tries to find files) ?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/618889/can-you-define-a-servers-locations-in-multiple-nginx-config-files

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are probably looking for Nginx's `include` function:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include

You can use it like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  […]
  include conf/location.conf;
}
```

include also accepts wildcards so you could also write

```
include include/*.conf;
```

to include every *.conf file in the directory *include*.

Comment: I considered this already but skipped it, because it would mean to edit the files content, rather than just unlinking files in the sites-enabled folder.

Comment: @ardukar so your solution was to use the sites-enabled folder?

Comment: I'm a little confused right now...

Comment: Sorry for answering so late! Seems like I didn't read the notification.. -.-  I am using FLXN's solution already. But that doesn't make me happy. Since I am building a server for a smaller company, where the administration is done solely via Browser, i'd rather not want to make changes inside a file. If a service is deactivated via browser, I want the subfolder (say 'location') in nginx to be deactivated as well, hence unlinking the config file in the sites-enabled folder seemed to be the best idea.

Comment: Please beware of the priority of the wildcard. Related: https://serverfault.com/a/361163/345785

Answer (score 8):

You can create site folders with

```
mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

# And then split your large `your_config.conf` file into smaller files into `sites-available/` with:

```
YOURCONF="/etc/nginx/conf.d/your_config.conf"
cd /etc/nginx
mkdir -p sites-available sites-enabled
cd  sites-available/
csplit "$YOURCONF" '/^\s*server\s*{*$/' {*}
for i in xx*; do
  new=$(grep -oPm1 '(?<=server_name).+(?=;)' $i|sed -e 's/\(\w\) /\1_/g'|xargs);
  if [[ -e $new.conf ]] ; then
    echo "" >>$new.conf
    cat "$i">>$new.conf
    rm "$i"
  else
    mv "$i" $new.conf
  fi
done
```

(I enhanced this from this source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9635153/1069083 )

Be sure to add this at the end inside the `http` block of your`/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

Note: comments outside the `server` blocks are cut into the bottom of each file, so there should be no comments BEFORE a `server` block. Move comments in the first line INSIDE the block instead, example:

```
 # don't put comments here
 server {
    # put your comments about domain xyz.org here
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.org;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast and adding the example, cool! :-)
I understand what I should do and what I shouldn't do. But I don't get the reason. What do you mean with _are cut into the bottom of each file_?

Comment: If you would put a comment above, it would end up in the wrong file

Comment: This moves entire `server` blocks into separate files which is nice but unhelpful to the OP who is trying move sets of `location` blocks _within a single_ `server` block into separate files.

Comment: To split by `location` instead of `server`, just change this in the `csplit` line

Comment: Doing that would write out orphaned `location` blocks that belong to no `server` without the `include` directives discussed in the top-voted answer?

Comment: I referred more to the overall question title. In this particular case you need both answers, this and the one by @FLXN