# Is it possible to import header from file - nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

Just started using my very first nginx server and I have added few header, but I was wondering, is it possible somehow to import those headers from different file?

Let,s say, I have a `_headers` file with such content:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Referrer-Policy "SAME-ORIGIN";
add_header Feature-Policy "geolocation 'none'; microphone 'none';";
```

And can I somehow import it into my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks like this is a possible thing! I used "include" directive for that and it worked pretty good!

Found it [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/707955/nginx-split-large-configuration-file)