# Apply same config to all server blocks

Tags: nginx

We have hundreds of sites running on an Nginx server, each one has it's own config file in `site-available` / `enabled` that contains their server blocks and are loaded by the `nginx.conf` in the `http` block by doing `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`.

Now i would like to block access to the sites for specific user agents (pesky bots), i was wondering if could apply something like:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "bot1|bot1|bot3") { return 444; }
```

to all sites without having to edit every individual site config files.

Could i add it in the `http` block, would that affect all server blocks included?

Is there a better way that won't have me code a script to update the hundreds of sites' config files?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/707963/8710 You can move some settings to a separate file and then include in the right locations.

Comment: @LexLi i would still need to edit the hundreds of files for each the sites