# Nginx giving precedence to subdomains based in alphabetical order of config files

Tags: nginx, ssl, certbot

TLDR: Nginx is giving precedence to subdomains in alphabetical order of the config files, and I want to know a way to prevent this from happening. This is *similar* to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/361134/nginx-includes-config-files-not-in-order) question, but I am more interested in improving my system.

I (had) two sections on my server: One for a static website, and one for my dokuwiki instance. I wanted dokuwiki to load when someone went to example.com, and the static website to load when someone went to static.example.com. Finally, I wanted wiki.example.com to always point to dokuwiki, in case the default changed.

To accomplish this, I had two files in /etc/nginx/sites-available.

**dokuwiki** (This is just a common dokuwiki config with certbot run on it)

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = wiki.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen               80;
    listen                   [::]:80;
    server_name          wiki.example.com example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
 
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
 
    server_name example.com www.example.com wiki.example.com;
 
    # Maximum file upload size is 4MB - change accordingly if needed
    client_max_body_size 4M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
 
    root /dokuwiki/dokuwiki-2020-07-29;
    index doku.php;
 
    #Remember to comment the below out when you're installing, and uncomment it when done.
    location ~ /(conf/|bin/|inc/|install.php) { deny all; }
 
    #Support for X-Accel-Redirect
    location ~ ^/data/ { internal ; }
 
    location ~ ^/lib.*\.(js|css|gif|png|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
 
    location / { try_files $uri $uri/ @dokuwiki; }
 
    location @dokuwiki {
        # rewrites "doku.php/" out of the URLs if you set the userwrite setting to .htaccess in dokuwiki config page
        rewrite ^/_media/(.*) /lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/_detail/(.*) /lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/_export/([^/]+)/(.*) /doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/(.*) /doku.php?id=$1&$args last;
    }
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /doku.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; #old php version
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**static**

```
server {
    root /var/www/example;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name static.example.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

This system worked exactly as I expected it to. However, I then added commafeed to my server. My goal was to access commafeed via rss.example.com. Commafeed runs on port 8082, so I did a proxy_pass to example.com/8082 in this file

**commafeed**

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    
    root /var/www/commafeed;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name rss.example.com www.rss.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8082/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

When I did this, I got a reset connection on my browser for *all* example.com domains, and this error message logged

```
example:/etc/nginx/sites-available# tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log -n 0
2021/09/28 03:10:36 [error] 32479#32479: *2317 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: <my ipv6 address>, server: [::]:443
2021/09/28 03:10:36 [error] 32479#32479: *2318 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: <my ipv6 address>, server: [::]:443
```

**However, when I renamed the file to "zcommafeed", everything worked as intended.** That is, all of the old subdomains worked as they did before, as well as rss.example.com pointing to commafeed.

Now, while this works, this seems to imply that there's a better way of doing this that doesn't involve paying attention to the alphabetical order of files. I am new to NGINX, so I would really appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 2):

The error message clearly says that the configuration is missing a TLS certificate for `rss.example.com`. Create a proper certificate / key pair for `rss.example.com` and `www.rss.example.com`, then the configuration will work properly.

Comment: And `listen` directives do not include `ssl` .

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is sorting the file includes containing the virtual hosts indeed. Because that's more comfortable to use and to understand the logic of selecting the default one - and this would be the first vhost include file when sorted alphabetically.

In fact you're looking for the `default` option to `listen` directive, that is used to terminate *all other sites* not matching the `server_name` mentioned in your `server {}` blocks.

Add the `default` option to the `listen` directive of the virtual host that should terminate all the requests if none `server_name` matched.